# Can someone help me figure out why my flutter path isn't found when using command prompt in Windows 11?

Tags: flutter, path, environment-variables, command-prompt

> [Edit Environment Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/so5Jv.png)
> [Command prompt exception message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwPLK.png)
> [flutter folder location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4ofT.png)
> [bin subfolder location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdjeB.png)

> I am unable to get the path to show up in command prompt for flutter that I just installed. I keep getting the same error message:
>
> "Unhandled exception:Exception: Cannot find the executable for 'where'. This can happen if the System32 folder (e.g. "C:\Windows\System32") is removed from the path environment variable."
>
> Then I tried adding "\Windows\System32" into the path environment variable and got the following error message:
>
> "'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

> [not recognized error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM4py.png)

> I have tried following several tutorials on Youtube for this but I can't seem to get it to work right. I tried copying and pasting the bin path into the environment variable like the guy did in the video, but that didn't work either.
>
> I am trying to follow a tutorial from freeCodeCamp, and he says it's important to have flutter accessible in command prompt. But he has a Mac so the commands are a little bit different which is why I had to find another tutorial just for this part.

> freeCodeCamp tutorial I want to follow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPvVD8t02U8&t=3123s flutter installation tutorial I'm trying to follow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=64RIw7jqQZw

Comment: As the error message says, `C:\Windows\System32` should be included in your system's `PATH` environment variable.   Is it?

Comment: It wasn't, so I added it and that's when I got the second error. "not recognized error"

Comment: Your `PATH` environment variable needs to have both `C:\Windows\System32` *and* `C:\Users\Kellie\flutter\bin`.  Ideally you should have left your *system* version of `PATH` unmodified and added the `flutter\bin` directory only to the `PATH` for your account (Windows will merge them dynamically).

Comment: I got the Welcome to Flutter! thing in cmd. But when I tried "flutter doctor" it says the check crashed and it only gave me a few of the checks. One of which is "Visual Studio not installed" but I do have it installed. I just don't know if it needs to be somewhere specific.

Comment: You don't *need* to use Visual Studio Code to use Flutter.  You can use whatever editor you want (but VS Code is recommended).  It's probably looking for VS Code in your `PATH`, so you should add that too...

Comment: Try to follow flutter official documentation it has stepwise information to install flutter successfully. [Refer this](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install)